# Como ler dois valores numéricos para lista numa mesma linha em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu sei que para se ler múltiplos valores por input numa mesma linha se usa o "split()", e para adicionar valores a listas, algum loop como "for" ou "while", mas gostaria de saber como juntar ambos para conseguir adicionar múltiplos valores numéricos a uma lista tendo todos estes inseridos por apenas uma linha.
Tentei algo como:

```
c = 0
n = input()
while c < n:
    X.append(c,input().split(' '))
    c+=1
```

Mas não funciona,então se alguém souber alguma solução,por favor,diga.

Comment: 1) Ao menos para mim, sua dúvida não está clara. Você escreveu uma frase de quatro linhas! Tente reformular o texto, explicando melhor cada um dos pontos que você está apresentando. 2) Onde você definiu `X`?

Comment: Colega, não consigo responder a sua pergunta, você quer uma lista flat ou uma lista de tuplas de tamanho n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método [extend()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) que estende uma lista com o conteúdo do argumento.

Como na pergunta você fala em "múltiplos valores numérico" use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para converter as entradas de `string` para `int`

```
>>> x = [0, 1]
>>> x.extend([int(i) for i in input().split(' ')])
2 3 4 5 6
>>> print(x)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Também é possível alcançar o mesmo resultado utilizando o operador de atribuição composta `+=` ao invés de `extend()`.

```
>>> x = [0, 1]
>>> x += [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
2 3 4 5 6
>>> print(x)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```